# Minimal working example of mixed Julia and C project on Windows

Tags: c, windows, dll, julia, portaudio

I'm looking for a simple, minimal working example for a Julia project that includes some C code as part of the project. I need the project to compile the C code into a *.dll and then have some Julia code that can successfully call a function from that *.dll on Windows.

I'm having a lot of trouble getting this to work on Windows, and it would be really helpful to just start from some example that I know actually works, and troubleshoot from there why my larger project isn't working.

My use case is calling the portaudio library for low-latency presentation of sounds, using a lock-less multi-threading model. This isn't really possible to write in julia at this point, that I know of: I really need a system level language like C. But I'd like the rest of the project to be in Julia.

Comment: I have, and I've had plenty of success calling c code from a 3rd party *.dll (e.g. installed via WinRPM.jl). But what I'm trying to do is create my own *.dll and call a function from that. Where should I ask for sample code?

Answer (score 3):

[This blog post](http://www.stochasticlifestyle.com/using-julias-c-interface-utilize-c-libraries/) contains pretty much a minimal working example. It compiles a small linker code to GSL and then writes about 10 lines of Julia to use it. It even in  that space shows how to pass a Julia-defined function to C.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I don't see anything specific to Windows in this blog post. I have no trouble getting this to work on Mac OS X (and I'm assuming the same would be true for Linux). I believe the issues I'm running into are related to the logistics of compiling and linking to a *.dll on Windows specifically.

Comment: Yeah, there's no Windows in there. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/julia-users/ZnIP2cqEemk) is not a perfect example, but it's very *very* close. I haven't run this code, but the poster claims that it compiles and runs successfully on Windows.

Comment: Update: using this example I've managed to get a working *.dll on Windows. The key point is that you need to make sure all dependencies for a dll can be found. You can use Dependency Walker (which is mentioned in the link) to figure out if you need to add/rename any dependent dll's to the directory you load your own dll from.